# Convert simd_quatf to SCNQuaternion

Tags: ios, swift, scenekit, simd

What is an easy way to use simd quaternion under SceneKit? I have a type simd_quatf and SCNNode.orientation needs SCNQuaternion. Both are same 4 items vectors, but Swift is making it hard to convert from one to other.

```
//pseudocode:
#import simd
#import SceneKit

var geometryNode : SCNNode = SCNNode()
let q1 = simd_quatf(angle: Float.pi, axis: SIMD3<Float>(1,0,0))
geometryNode.orientation = SCNQuaternion() <--- trouble here
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use can use [`simdOrientation`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/scenekit/scnnode/2881854-simdorientation) instead of `orientation`.

Comment: I used this to fix it: geometryNode2.orientation = SCNQuaternion(q.vector), were q type is simd_quat. But this is more elegant solution.